# Laser Printer producing streaky ink prints

Tags: printing, laser-printer

I recently got a Samsung C430W Laser printer with some empty colour toner cartridges (which I refilled myself) and a new third party blank toner cartridge. However, when I print there are streaky lines on the right hand side of the page ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twgf1.jpg)). If I print in colour, then there are streaks of black, yellow and magenta but if I print in black then I only get black streaks.

I have attached photos of the toner cartridges and drum below but nothing looks particularly out of the ordinary. There appears to be some slight ink spillage but I'm not sure where from since all of the cartridges are sealed up.

[Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUUfg.jpg), [Magenta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5mhg.jpg), [Cyan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCqFl.jpg), [Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiISf.jpg), [Drum 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiDxt.jpg), [Drum 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R54n0.jpg), [Orange Drum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpvh1.jpg), [Black Drum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsOwb.jpg)

Comment: What about the fuser(s)?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not sure what the fusers look like, but i've attached photos of the other two drums I could find to the OP. Cheers!

Comment: The "orange drum" is the fuser. Turn the printer off, let it cool down for a while, and inspect the fuser for damage.

Comment: You might just have some spilled ink from transportation that will eventually run out.